# How to find the volume of a solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the graphs of the equations about the line y=7?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

I cannot figure out how to solve this.  The region is bounded by $xy=7$, $y=1$, $y=8$ and $x=9$.  Revolving about the line $x=9$.

I came up with the following integral to solve this:

$\pi\int_{1}^{8}(9)^2-(7/y)^2dy$

The answer I got is $1646.587$.

What am I doing wrong? Did I set up the problem incorrectly?

[image]

Comment: Could it be that you take the difference of the squares instead of the square of the difference?

Comment: I have tried $\pi\int_{1}^{8}(9-(7/y))^2dy$ as well, but it still says my answer is incorrect? Doing it this way I got 1092.851.

Comment: So, what is the "correct" answer according to your source?

Comment: I do not know the correct answer.  It is for a Calculus 2 WebAssign homework assignment.

Comment: I dont know that tool, but maybe you have to enter the exact answer, with pi and logarithms?

Comment: Yea I am not sure but I have been trying to figure this one problem out for a while now.  Everything looks right doesn't it?

Comment: Hit the "Talk to tutor" button? :)

Answer (score 1):

A general tip in the case you are not revolving around a coordinate axis is to transform your expressions so that you are. Your situation looks like this:

[image: graphs1]

If you shift $9$ steps to the left (i.e. replace all $x$ by $x+9$), then it looks like this

[image: graphs2]

So, the domain that revolves is bounded by the curves
$$
(x+9)y=7,\quad y=1,\quad y=8,\quad\text{and}\quad x=0.
$$
The first equation gives
$$
x=\frac{7}{y}-9.
$$
Thus, the volume you look for is given by the integral
$$
\int_1^8\pi(7/y-9)^2\,dy.
$$